# How to resolve error showing like filename used twice

Tags: ios, iphone, compiler-errors, swift2

I am working in swift with Xcode 7.3.1. Now i got error showing like **file name used twice** and i am stuck with this following error.

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/mac/Desktop/develop/myApp/Manager.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: filename "Manager.swift" used twice: '/Users/mac/Desktop/develop/myApp/Manager.swift' and '/Users/mac/Desktop/develop/myApp/MyApp/module/Manager.swift'
```

Could you please help me

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838184/xcode-swift-filename-used-twice-build-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838184/xcode-swift-filename-used-twice-build-error)

Comment: @Lion I already tried with above link. Its not working.

Comment: You have path already, you can go to that folder and can delete duplicate file!!

Comment: Try This.  Open your project folder and open DerivedData folder after that select ModuleCache folder and delete it. Take a backup first. Hope it help

Comment: And also clean the project by pressing these keys "option+command+shift+K" and then build the project.

Comment: I solve it by [Remove the used twice file from Compile Sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48339399/6521116). Refer to [Xcode/Swift 'filename used twice' build error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34838184/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue, so hopefully this helps.

Open your project file (`ProjectName.xcodeproj`) in a text editor (I chose Sublime), and then search for the file entry (`Manager.swift`). If you find two entries for it in there, then delete one. If you are not sure if you will delete the right one, you can delete both and then re-add the file to your project afterwards.

Since you are editing your project file, it is highly recommended to make sure you have a fresh commit prior to this to avoid any potential loss of data.

Answer (score 0):

I had actually the same problem.
I found solution in Recovered References folder.
Just removed reference to `FileThatUsedTwice.swift`
Hope it will help you