# Multiple commands produced error xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios12, tlyshynavbar

I am working on an iOS app. It is working fine in Xcode 9.4.1, but when I build it in Xcode 10 it gives me following error:

```
:-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Dev-iphonesimulator/TLYShyNavBar/TLYShyNavBar.framework/Info.plist':
1) Target 'TLYShyNavBar' has copy command from '/Users/.../Desktop/Workspace/iOS/.../Pods/TLYShyNavBar/TLYShyNavBar/Info.plist' to '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Dev-iphonesimulator/TLYShyNavBar/TLYShyNavBar.framework/Info.plist'
2) Target 'TLYShyNavBar' has process command with input '/Users/.../Desktop/Workspace/iOS/.../Pods/Target Support Files/TLYShyNavBar/Info.plist'
```

I tried the solutions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50718018/3824808) but they didn't work.
Any help provided is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For me, nothing worked from the post. I deleted info file, renamed and mapped correctly in build settings - it is working fine now. Hope this might help you.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719379/3024579

Comment: One more solution especially for case with pods files – deintegrate and install pods: exec commands in 'Terminal' `$ cd path/to/project_toot` then `$ pod deintegrate` and `$ pod install`.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

I found the solution for this build error, for anybody else having the same issue with Xcode 10 build system, follow the following steps to fix it:

> 1. In Xcode, go to File->Project/Workspace settings.
> 2. Change the build system to Legacy Build system.

[image]

It will resolve the build issue with the new Xcode 10.

If you want to work with the new build system, then you can find the troubleshooting help [from this apple Xcode help page](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev621201fb0).

> Edit:
>
> I was able to resolve the issue with the new Xcode build system by
>   removing the duplicate info.plist from the Pod by following steps:
>
> Solution - Open target > Build phase > Copy Bundle Resource/Compile
>   Sources > removed info.plist from here

Comment: If you're using xcbuild directly (for example on a CI) then you can set the same via this flag: `-UseModernBuildSystem=NO`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51205222/851490

Comment: I'm getting same error, and i'm not using pods. It's complaining about some icon file being copied multiple times. And since Apple doesn't care about developers, there's zero info about where these alleged conflicts are. So thanks for tip on switching back to legacy build mode.

Comment: There is better solution...here-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719379

Comment: I tried it but just this solved for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451421/2238515

Comment: I had the same issue once update x-code to Version 10.1 (10B61). Simply deleted info.plist from Copy Bundle Resources
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089254/1823043

Comment: Apparently now we can't have multiple files with the same name even if they are in different directories. THANKS APPLE!! At least they left us the legacy build (for now).