# How can I use the legacy build system with Xcode 10's `xcodebuild`?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, xcode10

I'd like to use the new build system of Xcode 10 for development, but our build in our continuous integration system fails since the `xcarchive` produced has an issue: the `Info.plist` in the `xcarchive` is missing the `ApplicationProperties` key and the information therein!

It turns out switching back to the legacy build system fixes this. This can be done in the workspace settings (File > Workspace Settings… > Build System). But I would prefer to keep the new build system for development and only use the legacy build system for CI builds.

Is there a way to make `xcodebuild` use the legacy build system without modifying the workspace?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

There is an (as of yet undocumented) flag in `xcodebuild`: `-UseModernBuildSystem=<value>`. The value can be either `0` or `NO` to use the legacy ("original") build system, or `1` or `YES` to use the new build system.

For example:

```
xcodebuild -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -scheme Bar -configuration Release -archivePath /path/to/Foo.xcarchive clean archive -UseModernBuildSystem=NO
```

(`-UseNewBuildSystem=<value>` seems to work as well; this flags was introduced in Xcode 9 but I suspect `UseModernBuildSystem` is going to be the "official" flag for this.)

Comment: Do you think this is a bug with Xcode or something else going on where that entry in the plist is missing?

Comment: @cynistersix: I think so, yes. There seem to be other issues with the new build system as well: for example, if you're using CocoaPods and change a file in a pod the new build system doesn't correctly recompile it, you have to clean the project first. My guess is that since the new buildsystem is an improvement but not perfect yet they also left in the support for the legacy buildsystem.

Answer (score 51):

Change build system to `Legacy Build System` from `New Build System` and vice versa.

Open Xcode --> Select File -->Select Workspace Settings

[image]

Change Build System to Legacy Build System from New Build System --> Click Done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but as stated in the question, that's already known. This question is about the `xcodebuild` tool.

Comment: In Xcode 11, this menu item is called Project Settings

Comment: xcode 15 does not have this section anymore

Answer (score 39):

To extend DarkDust's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51205222/9511678), in case you're using **fastlane** for automated builds, additional parameters such as `UseModernBuildSystem` can be passed through `xcargs`:

```
build_app(
   // ... other necessary parameters,
   xcargs: "-UseModernBuildSystem=NO"
)
```

Answer (score 38):

To select Xcode 10's build system:

In Xcode, go to:  File -> Project Settings (or Workspace Settings)-> Build System

From there you can select `New Build System (Default)` or `Legacy Build System`

Hope this help makes this easier.

Comment: This will change project settings. The question was about _xcodebuild using the legacy build system **without modifying the workspace**_

Answer (score 14):

Currently, I'm using Xcode version **12.0** *(12A7209)* and follow the below steps and then you can use legacy build mode:

1. Workspace Setting:

   [image]
2. Set the legacy build mode:

   [image]

Comment: @AmerllicA I am getting the below error after changing to Legacy build system. The legacy build system does not support building projects with Swift when SWIFT_ENABLE_LIBRARY_EVOLUTION is enabled.