# Xcode legacy build system in the AppCode

Tags: xcode, appcode, xcode-build-settings

I am working on xcode now, but I want switch to AppCode to test it's capabilities. Problem is, my project is quite old, and wont build without legacy build system turned on. I know how to switch legacy system in the xcode, and I found how to force it from `xcodebuild` settings in this question ([How can I use the legacy build system with Xcode 10's `xcodebuild`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205221/how-can-i-use-the-legacy-build-system-with-xcode-10s-xcodebuild)), but I didn't similar option in appcode, or there I can set `xcodebuild` settings in it.
Does anyone know anything on this topic?