# "Building for iOS, but the embedded framework 'xxx.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator"

Tags: ios, xcode12

When upgrading to Xcode 12.3, getting the error:

```
Building for iOS, but the embedded framework 'opus.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator
```

But everything is ok before the update.

Comment: same problem for me!

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65303304/xcode-12-3-building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-and-embedded-framework-wa

Comment: A temporary workaround (that is working for me) is to use the legacy build system https://stackoverflow.com/a/54058682

Comment: There is a workaround if you are using Cocoapods. Frameworks distributed via cocoapods are not directly embedded and target integrity check doesn't "see" them.
So you can just package your framework as a local pod:
1) create podspec and reference the framework
`spec.public_header_files = "YourFramework.framework/Headers/*.h"
spec.source_files = "YourFramework/Headers/*.h"
spec.vendored_frameworks = "YourFramework"`
2) reference framework from podfile

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65303304/xcode-12-3-building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-and-embedded-framework-wa],this worked for me! thanks@TomKnapen

Answer (score 15):

[Xcode Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H19T.png)

It could be helped to try to set your "Validate Workspace" of "Build Options" in "Build Settings" as Yes.

Comment: For M1 Mac, opening in Rosetta + above option helped me

Comment: Mine is already set to "No", and this error still occurs.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: This was an observation that could help those who use Carthage.

Apparently the most popular solution to this problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306886/6791677) answer.

> setting **Validate Workspace** to Yes in the Build Settings tab

Also, the observation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65315026/6791677) answer is correct

> I'm afraid that this is actually the correct error and the framework
> shouldn't contain iOS and iOS Simulator code at the same time. Apple
> tries to force us to use XCFramework for this purpose. They started it
> in XCode 11 and just tightened up the restrictions.

Every other solution (other than xcframework usage) seems to become increasingly temporary in the coming Xcode versions.

---

This is an issue if you are using **Carthage** and you have added a framework with `Embed & Sign`.

[image]

For this to work properly you have to follow the [steps](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/README.md#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos) that Carthage page provide:

> If you're building for iOS, tvOS, or watchOS
>
> 1. Create a Cartfile that lists the frameworks you’d like to use in your project.
> 2. Run `carthage update`. This will fetch dependencies into a Carthage/Checkouts folder, then build each one or download a
>    pre-compiled framework.
> 3. Open your application targets’ *General* settings tab. For Xcode 11.0 and higher, in the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section, drag and drop each framework you want to use from the
>    Carthage/Build folder on disk. Then, in the "Embed"  section,
>    select "Do Not Embed" from the pulldown menu for each item added. For
>    Xcode 10.x and lower, in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"
>    section, drag and drop each framework you want to use from the
>    Carthage/Build folder on disk.
> 4. On your application targets’ *Build Phases* settings tab, click the *+* icon and choose *New Run Script Phase*. Create a Run Script in which you specify your shell (ex: `/bin/sh`), add the following
>    contents to the script area below the shell:
>
>    ```sh
>    /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
>    ```
> 5. Create a file named `input.xcfilelist` and a file named `output.xcfilelist`
> 6. Add the paths to the frameworks you want to use to your `input.xcfilelist`. For example:
>
>    ```
>    $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Result.framework
>    $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveSwift.framework
>    $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveCocoa.framework
>    ```
> 7. Add the paths to the copied frameworks to the `output.xcfilelist`. For example:
>
>    ```
>    $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/Result.framework
>    $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/ReactiveSwift.framework
>    $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/ReactiveCocoa.framework
>    ```
>
>    With output files specified alongside the input files, Xcode only needs to run the script when the input files have changed or the
>    output files are missing. This means dirty builds will be faster when
>    you haven't rebuilt frameworks with Carthage.
> 8. Add the `input.xcfilelist` to the "Input File Lists" section of the Carthage run script phase
> 9. Add the `output.xcfilelist` to the "Output File Lists" section of the Carthage run script phase

Maybe this is a temporary fix for other cases also. (dependencies that **are not build** with Carthage)

Comment: I'm having OP's issue, but I'm using CocoaPods instead of Carthage

Comment: yeah same for me. Not using Carthage.

Comment: This issue happens **regardless** of Carthage.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I moved my edit to the top of the answer. Original answer solves a similar issue occurred when using Carthage.