# Unity Cloud Build iOS error Multiple commands produce

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, unity3d-cloud-build

Im developing my mobile game on iOS by Unity Cloud Build. Im getting errors:

```
370:  + Building with Xcode 10.0
371: ▸ ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/Info.plist':
372: ▸ ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/MPAdBrowserController-PartialInfo.plist':
373: ▸ ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/MPAdBrowserController~iphone.nib':
374: ▸ ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/MPAdBrowserController~ipad.nib':
375: ▸ ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/MPAdBrowserController.nib':
376: ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/Info.plist':
377: ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/MPAdBrowserController-PartialInfo.plist':
378: ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/MPAdBrowserController~iphone.nib':
379: ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/MPAdBrowserController~ipad.nib':
380: ❌;  error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/MPAdBrowserController.nib':
381: ▸ error: Multiple commands produce '/BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fibhmfoypbvnivfzuiccjoizjttf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/APPLICATION_PATH/block.app/MPAdBrowserController.nib':
```

I found a lot of solutions which work in Xcode, but i dont know if i can access things like this by cloud building. Like this: [Legacy Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071090/multiple-commands-produced-error-xcode-10) or  [Remove info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce)