# Xcode 10 GM multiple command produce... Pods issues

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode10

Just switched to xcode 10 Golden Master and start getting the error with one of my pods, [FDTake](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake). Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce) thread but I don't have a plist in my build phases, so it didn't work. Is this issue pod related?

```
Showing All Messages
:-1: Multiple commands produce '***/Xcode/DerivedData/app-fgyqhwrvkbjquheilgwhyjltujtz/Build/Products/Dev-iphonesimulator/FDTake/FDTake.framework/Info.plist':
1) Target 'FDTake' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '***/GoogleDrive/dev/_ios/Work/sutulp/Pods/FDTake/Source/Info.plist' to '***Xcode/DerivedData/app-fgyqhwrvkbjquheilgwhyjltujtz/Build/Products/Dev-iphonesimulator/FDTake/FDTake.framework/Info.plist'
2) Target 'FDTake' (project 'Pods') has process command with output '***Xcode/DerivedData/app-fgyqhwrvkbjquheilgwhyjltujtz/Build/Products/Dev-iphonesimulator/FDTake/FDTake.framework/Info.plist'
```

I also tried to remove the derived data folder, but it didn't work either. Tried to clean the project and so on – no luck. Any advice is appreciated.

Switch to old build system will not be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very similar to this question: [Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50718018/7932935)

Here is a link to the most voted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719379

If this doesn't work, you may have a Pod dependency cycle for that pod.

In my case, there was such an issue.

In my pod project the target Lock had a target dependency to the `Lock-Auth0` framework so I had to remove the line for "Lock-Auth0" for the Lock target by going to `Build Settings > Target Dependencies > & Copy Bundle Resources` (this will be undone if you run `pod install` again) .

I took a look at the Lock.podspec and realized that the dependency has been removed on the latest version so upgrading to the most recent version of the Pod will be my next step.

Hope this helps.

[here is a screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrXi0.jpg)

Comment: Dear Carlos, you say that "upgrading to the most version..." will be your next step. Does this mean you have not solved your problem yet? You should only answer with a solution that you are 100% it has worked at least for you.

Comment: Regina, Removing the pod dependency worked for me and 100% of my teammates you posted a link to the same answer I referred which helped but it was not a full solution due to the Pod dependency between Lock and the Lock-Auth0 framework. 

I added a caveat: (this will be undone if you run pod install again) you may have missed that. So in some cases a specific Pod may have a dependency problem uncovered by Xcode10 new build system.

The latest version of Lock actually addressed the dependency issue which was my problem similar to Max's issue:
https://github.com/auth0/Lock.swift/releases

Comment: Ok, I had to select a different target, specifically FDTake in Pods (my case) and THEN delete the info.plist. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I had same problem with Xcode 10 GM. In my case Cocoapods not found. So, require to re-installed it.

- To find if Cocoapods is installed or not run command on terminal.   **pod --version**
- if the result is `Not Found` Pods is not installed. So, run command on terminal **$ sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org**

> Hope it's helps to you...