# Xcode 10 archive build failed

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10

I'm getting the errors below when trying to archive the app. Any idea how to resolve this?

> :-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/gb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB-ggeaxhzkqxunxvenbvbwxczukaqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GB/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libyoga.a':
>   1) Target 'yoga' has a command with output
>   '/Users/gb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB-ggeaxhzkqxunxvenbvbwxczukaqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GB/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libyoga.a'
>   2) Target 'yoga' has a command with output
>   '/Users/gb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB-ggeaxhzkqxunxvenbvbwxczukaqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GB/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libyoga.a'
>
> :-1: Multiple commands produce
>   '/Users/gb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB-ggeaxhzkqxunxvenbvbwxczukaqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GB/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libReact.a':
>   1) Target 'React' has a command with output
>   '/Users/gb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB-ggeaxhzkqxunxvenbvbwxczukaqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GB/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libReact.a'
>   2) Target 'React' has a command with output
>   '/Users/gb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB-ggeaxhzkqxunxvenbvbwxczukaqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GB/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libReact.a'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce)

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 6):

You can try to change the build system to Legacy

File > Workspace Settings > Build System > Legacy Build System.

Comment: Works everytime

Comment: Perfect answer for this issue !

Answer (score 2):

I am using Cocoapods installing depedencies for google map ios and get the same error with duplicate libyoga.a and libReact.a.

It is fix by adding to Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end

    if target.name == "yoga"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

Then reinstall pod.

Thanks to [Senke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5713090/senke) post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54338797/8143857

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CocoaPods, have this problem, and don't want to change to the Legacy Build System:

Make sure that the subspec combinations of any extension targets are also included in their host app. Examine the Podfile.lock to investigate and make appropriate adjustments to the Podfile.

The CocoaPods team is investigating a better solution.

Detailed discussion at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8206

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Build System to `Legacy` and try rebuild:
File => Workspace Settings => Build System => Legacy Build System

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, and now I finally found a fix!

I tried to remove the yoga target in the Podfile's post_install step, as jtian suggested:

```
if target.name == "yoga"
  target.remove_from_project
end
```

This didn't work though, because then I got a linker error that said Yoga couldn't be found... so I scrapped that.

The fix was that I found some duplicate font references in the XCode project. I removed the duplicates and that fixed it. :)