# Xcode 10 - App not updated after building and installing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

after the latest update of Xcode 10 I have the problem that when I try to build and install the app to my IPhone 7, Xcode seems to install the app, but I cannot see any changes when I try to change for example a color or a constraint in Main.storyboard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce/52418062?noredirect=1#comment91822944_52418062 Follow this question Hope this will help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the phone.

Different issue but I was having an issue running an XCUITest on device after upgrading to Xcode 10, and restart solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode and the simulator and then Restart you computer.

If that doesn’t work try using a different simulator.