# Xcode 10 build error - Multiple commands produce info.plist

Tags: xcode, info.plist, xcode10

I recently updated to Xcode 10 but now get this whenever I try to run my build:

```
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/shiningsunnyday/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aiRun-aogoneumhlleekecmbglgiyifpwy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/aiRun.app/Info.plist':
1) Target 'aiRun' (project 'aiRun') has copy command from '/Users/shiningsunnyday/Documents/GitHub/running_app/RUN BABY/aiRun/aiRun/Info.plist' to '/Users/shiningsunnyday/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aiRun-aogoneumhlleekecmbglgiyifpwy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/aiRun.app/Info.plist'
2) Target 'aiRun' (project 'aiRun') has process command with output '/Users/shiningsunnyday/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aiRun-aogoneumhlleekecmbglgiyifpwy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/aiRun.app/Info.plist'
```

I can remove my Info.plist's target membership and it works but I need the custom-set key values inside it. What do I do?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce

Comment: this works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719379/367006

Answer (score 0):

> Workspace Project > Build Settings > find[Command+F] > info.plist >
>   Packaging > info.plist File - [your_target/info.plist]

The above method is the cleanest answer.

> [XCode - File - Workspace Settings - New Build System(Default)]