# xcode 10 migration error getting segment fault 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, ios12

After migration of Xcode to 10, an iOS project - which was building and running perfectly on previous Xcode 9 - is crashing during compilation with "Segmentation fault 11"

I did upgrade my MacOS to Mojave, but the issue is still there.

I get the following error:
[image]

> 1. While emitting SIL for 
>      'application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' at
>
>    /Users/swanandpatil/Desktop/omerApp/CustomerApp/AppDelegate.swift:955:5
> 2. While silgen emitFunction SIL function 
>      "@$S17CustomerApp0C8DelegateC11application_48didRegisterForRemoteNotifications WithDeviceTokenySo13UIApplicationC_10Foundation4DataVtF".
>      for 'application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' at /Users/swanandpatil/Desktop/RSA247CustomerApp/RSA247CustomerApp/AppDelegate.swift:955:5
>      error: Segmentation fault: 11

Below is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    //print("deviceToken is \(deviceToken)");

    if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey:"fcm_tokenNew")
        let token2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"fcm_tokenNew") as? String
        print("FCM TOKEN2 IS\(describing: token2 )");
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that the issue is related to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

Comment: Please don't post only a screenshot, bu copy/past the whole error, not only "segment fault 11", but what leads to it, what's just above it.

Comment: I assume it's an Xcode bug. You'll have to post the code (AppDelegate.swift, line 955, and surroundings).

Comment: This is the complete error   1. While emitting SIL for 'application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' at /Users/swanandpatil/Desktop/RSA247CustomerApp/RSA247CustomerApp/AppDelegate.swift:955:5
2. While silgen emitFunction SIL function "@$S17RSA247CustomerApp0C8DelegateC11application_48didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceTokenySo13UIApplicationC_10Foundation4DataVtF".
 for 'application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' at /Users/swanandpatil/Desktop/RSA247CustomerApp/RSA247CustomerApp/AppDelegate.swift:955:5
error: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        //print("deviceToken is \(deviceToken)");
        
        if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        
      UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey:"fcm_tokenNew")
       let token2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"fcm_tokenNew") as? String
        print("FCM TOKEN2 IS\(describing: token2 )");
         }
        
        
    }

Comment: I tried commenting this function but no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you found an Xcode compiler bug.

The problem is here:

```
print("FCM TOKEN2 IS\(describing: token2 )");
```

The correct syntax would be:

```
 print("FCM TOKEN2 IS\(String(describing:token2))");
```

The compiler should give you a meaningful error message, but instead is crashing.

I already filed a radar:
https://openradar.appspot.com/45330067

Comment: :-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/asd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomerApp-fqcceceikstdqzctsjuwfwrspvad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyGif/SwiftyGif.framework/Info.plist':
1) Target 'SwiftyGif' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/swanandpatil/Desktop/CustomerApp/Pods/SwiftyGif/SwiftyGif/Info.plist' to '/Users/swanandpatil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomerApp-fqcceceikstdqzctsjuwfwrspvad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyGif/SwiftyGif.framework/Info.plist'

Comment: 2) Target 'SwiftyGif' (project 'Pods') has process command with output '/Users/swanandpatil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomerApp-fqcceceikstdqzctsjuwfwrspvad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyGif/SwiftyGif.framework/Info.plist'

Comment: @user2606884 Please mark my answer as "accepted" if it solves your problem. To your second problem: This is something completely different. Typically, you should create individual questions for individual problems. In your special case, you could also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce