# Why do I get this error with iphone simulator in info.plist?

Tags: ios-simulator, info.plist

I am using Swift (Xcode) to create a mobile app. When I want to preview the app through the iPhone simulator (using run & build), I get an error:

> error: Multiple commands produce
>   '/Users/lewishomeoffice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PayUp-bcrlkqerfcqsvkbcmzpfzffcnusg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PayUp.app/Info.plist':
>
> 1) Target 'PayUp' (project 'PayUp') has copy command from
>   '/Users/lewishomeoffice/Desktop/PayUp
>   Assets/PayUp/PayUp/PayUp/Info.plist' to
>   '/Users/lewishomeoffice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PayUp-bcrlkqerfcqsvkbcmzpfzffcnusg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PayUp.app/Info.plist'
>
> 2) Target 'PayUp' (project 'PayUp') has process command with output
>   '/Users/lewishomeoffice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PayUp-bcrlkqerfcqsvkbcmzpfzffcnusg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PayUp.app/Info.plist'

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What were you trying to do? What code were you running? You will have more success in getting answers if you provide a complete minimal sample that reproduces the issue

Comment: swift code. I am using Xcode to create the mobile app. I'm a beginner so bare with me! But I went to run & build the app to preview it in the iPhone simulator, and it threw me that error.

Comment: No worries, SO can be hard to get used to at first and we are all doing our best to improve the community.  I have placed an edit of your question in the review queue to include the information you provided, as an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce this might help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce)