# pod repo push error:Multiple commands produce

Tags: cocoapods

I have a project that needs to be uploaded to my private pods. Because it depends others and there is an error: Multiple commands produce. I have set my xcode like that：File - worksapce - build system - Legacy Build System.It can run on top of my xcode success.

But when I execute the command: pod repo push XXX XXX. Podspec - sources = 'xxx, https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs' --verbose --allow-warnings --use-libraries. The mistake was repeated:

```
  Build system information
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/joker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fdhxxtrwyvhdkcapwibarbetxoyu/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app/Info.plist':
    1) That command depends on command in Target 'App' (project 'App'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
    2) Target 'App' (project 'App') has process command with output '/Users/joker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fdhxxtrwyvhdkcapwibarbetxoyu/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app/Info.plist'

    ** BUILD FAILED **

   Testing with `xcodebuild`.
 -> XXX (89)
    - WARN  | url: The URL (https://gitee.com/Becent/BCStarRocket) is not reachable.
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
```

Testing with `xcodebuild`, xcodebuild:  note is Using new build system, not Legacy Build System.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be occurring because of multiple Plist or other files within App-

*Solution -> Open target -> Build phases > Copy Bundle Resources* and remove info.plist from there.

[Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce)