# Duplicate info.plist files when using pods

Tags: swift

I'm using my own Pods, and I've got 4 that work in my current project.

However, when I do a pod install of the 4, each one has its own info.plist so predictably I get an error of duplicated files.

[image]

I can remove the reference to each info.plist from my development pods but I have to repeat this process after each pod install.

I understand I can legacy build (not an ideal solution), and the plist files can be played around with in the build settings (which does not seem to work in this case). The easiest and best way therefore seems the manual deletion.

What is the correct way to approach this problem which means I don't have to manually remove the plist files each time.

PodSpec file:

```
#
#  Be sure to run `pod spec lint GameManager.podspec' to ensure this is a
#  valid spec and to remove all comments including this before submitting the spec.
#
#  To learn more about Podspec attributes see http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html
#  To see working Podspecs in the CocoaPods repo see https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  # ―――  Spec Metadata  ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  These will help people to find your library, and whilst it
  #  can feel like a chore to fill in it's definitely to your advantage. The
  #  summary should be tweet-length, and the description more in depth.
  #

  s.name         = "GameManager"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of GameManager."

  # This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
  #   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
  #   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
  #   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
  #   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!
  s.description  = <<-DESC
    A tested, reusable FameManager

                   DESC

  s.homepage     = "http://www.test.com/GameManager"
  # s.screenshots  = "www.example.com/screenshots_1.gif", "www.example.com/screenshots_2.gif"


  # ―――  Spec License  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Licensing your code is important. See http://choosealicense.com for more info.
  #  CocoaPods will detect a license file if there is a named LICENSE*
  #  Popular ones are 'MIT', 'BSD' and 'Apache License, Version 2.0'.
  #

  # s.license      = "MIT (example)"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "FILE_LICENSE" }


  # ――― Author Metadata  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Specify the authors of the library, with email addresses. Email addresses
  #  of the authors are extracted from the SCM log. E.g. $ git log. CocoaPods also
  #  accepts just a name if you'd rather not provide an email address.
  #
  #  Specify a social_media_url where others can refer to, for example a twitter
  #  profile URL.
  #

  s.author             = { "Steven Curtis" => "stevenpcurtis@hotmail.com" }
  # Or just: s.author    = "Steven Curtis"
  # s.authors            = { "Steven Curtis" => "stevenpcurtis@hotmail.com" }
  # s.social_media_url   = "http://twitter.com/Steven Curtis"

  # ――― Platform Specifics ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  If this Pod runs only on iOS or OS X, then specify the platform and
  #  the deployment target. You can optionally include the target after the platform.
  #

  # s.platform     = :ios
  # s.platform     = :ios, "5.0"

  #  When using multiple platforms
  # s.ios.deployment_target = "5.0"
  # s.osx.deployment_target = "10.7"
  # s.watchos.deployment_target = "2.0"
  # s.tvos.deployment_target = "9.0"


  # ――― Source Location ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Specify the location from where the source should be retrieved.
  #  Supports git, hg, bzr, svn and HTTP.
  #

 #  s.source       = { :git => "http://EXAMPLE/GameManager.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
 s.source = { :git => "/Users/stevencurtis/Documents/CommercialApps/Frameworks/GameManager", :tag => "#{s.version}" }


  # ――― Source Code ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  CocoaPods is smart about how it includes source code. For source files
  #  giving a folder will include any swift, h, m, mm, c & cpp files.
  #  For header files it will include any header in the folder.
  #  Not including the public_header_files will make all headers public.
  #

 s.source_files  = "Classes", "GameManager/**/*.*"
  s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"

  # s.public_header_files = "Classes/**/*.h"


  # ――― Resources ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  A list of resources included with the Pod. These are copied into the
  #  target bundle with a build phase script. Anything else will be cleaned.
  #  You can preserve files from being cleaned, please don't preserve
  #  non-essential files like tests, examples and documentation.
  #

  # s.resource  = "icon.png"
  # s.resources = "Resources/*.png"

  # s.preserve_paths = "FilesToSave", "MoreFilesToSave"


  # ――― Project Linking ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Link your library with frameworks, or libraries. Libraries do not include
  #  the lib prefix of their name.
  #

  # s.framework  = "SomeFramework"
  # s.frameworks = "SomeFramework", "AnotherFramework"

  # s.library   = "iconv"
  # s.libraries = "iconv", "xml2"


  # ――― Project Settings ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  If your library depends on compiler flags you can set them in the xcconfig hash
  #  where they will only apply to your library. If you depend on other Podspecs
  #  you can include multiple dependencies to ensure it works.

  # s.requires_arc = true

  # s.xcconfig = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" }
  # s.dependency "JSONKit", "~> 1.4"

end
```

Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ExampleQuizAndGame' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ExampleQuizAndGame

    pod 'HTTPManager', :path => '/Users/stevencurtis/Documents/CommercialApps/Frameworks/HTTPManager'
    pod 'DataManager', :path => '/Users/stevencurtis/Documents/CommercialApps/Frameworks/DataManager'
    pod 'GameManager', :path => '/Users/stevencurtis/Documents/CommercialApps/Frameworks/GameManager'
    pod 'QuizManager', :path => '/Users/stevencurtis/Documents/CommercialApps/Frameworks/QuizManager'


  target 'ExampleQuizAndGameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ExampleQuizAndGameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719379/5464805. It may help.

Comment: I don't believe setting to legacy build settings (which works) is the correct approach. I already have a poor solution to this, I'm looking for a good one.

Comment: Maybe you can show how are you creating your own pods, can you show the Podspec file?

Comment: Thanks for the podspec, I think everything looks ok, maybe you can also share the `podfile` you are using on your current project?

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns I am not talking about the legacy build setting, this is never a solution. The solution I linked is about bundle resources that are copied from pods.

Comment: Which also doesn't work, as the plist files are not listed there

Answer (score 1):

In your pod repo, move the Info.plist up from your source code directory and into the project directory. Also, remove it from your project source files. As long as the project has the path to the Info.plist, it doesn't need to be a project source file.

That worked for me.