# I cant build an iOS project

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to build my project I get this same error

> error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/shaka0241/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutores-ckkpuvpkfwcscbfxzqbzibwjihlk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/tutores.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework':
>   1) Target 'tutores' has copy command from '/Users/shaka0241/ios-tutores/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework' to '/Users/shaka0241/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutores-ckkpuvpkfwcscbfxzqbzibwjihlk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/tutores.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
>   2) That command depends on command in Target 'tutores': script phase “Carthage Copy Frameworks”

Comment: did you delete your derived data?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean build folder and try deleting the DerivedData folder (and re-build)
2. Check all your Info.plist files for any inconsistencies (especially when working with SiriKitIntents)
3. Check your Target Memberships & frameworks you import

Those solved it whenever I had this problem..

Also possible dup: 
[Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50718018/9506784)