# Xcode 11.2 Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, build, compiler-errors

Running Xcode 11.2 and can not seem to find much information on this error that occurs when building my project.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the last line before the error:

> CompileAssetCatalog /Users/nes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BearAcademy-cabkimmshebxeicjmqphvvwbpzmc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BearAcademy.app /Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Assets.xcassets /Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Preview\ Content/Preview\ Assets.xcassets (in target 'BearAcademy' from project 'BearAcademy')
>       cd /Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/nes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BearAcademy-cabkimmshebxeicjmqphvvwbpzmc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BearAcademy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BearAcademy.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/nes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BearAcademy-cabkimmshebxeicjmqphvvwbpzmc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BearAcademy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BearAcademy.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --filter-for-device-model iPhone12,5 --filter-for-device-os-version 13.2 --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix nes.tl.BearAcademy.sticker-pack. --development-region en --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 13.2 --platform iphonesimulator --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile /Users/nes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BearAcademy-cabkimmshebxeicjmqphvvwbpzmc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BearAcademy.app /Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Assets.xcassets /Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Preview\ Content/Preview\ Assets.xcassets

2019-11-09 22:51:55.323 ibtoold[2285:60606] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
    TMPDIR = "/var/folders/gz/t9q9v6pn27jgq69f60q_nvm80000gn/T/0B228C3B-5BE3-455D-9960-304C1022B1B9";
}
CoreGraphics PDF has logged an error. Set environment variable "CG_PDF_VERBOSE" to learn more.
2019-11-09 22:51:55.658 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[2294:60844] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Assets.xcassets/splash-logo-big.imageset/splash-logo-big.pdf
2019-11-09 22:51:55.659 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[2294:60844] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Assets.xcassets/splash-logo-big.imageset/splash-logo-big.pdf
2019-11-09 22:51:55.660 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[2294:60844] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Assets.xcassets/splash-logo-big.imageset/splash-logo-big.pdf
2019-11-09 22:51:55.660 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[2294:60844] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Assets.xcassets/splash-logo-big.imageset/splash-logo-big.pdf
/* com.apple.actool.errors */
: error: Distill failed for unknown reasons.
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
/Users/nes/Desktop/BearAcademy/BearAcademy/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/nes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BearAcademy-cabkimmshebxeicjmqphvvwbpzmc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BearAcademy.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
/Users/nes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BearAcademy-cabkimmshebxeicjmqphvvwbpzmc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BearAcademy.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
/Users/nes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BearAcademy-cabkimmshebxeicjmqphvvwbpzmc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BearAcademy.app/Assets.car
/Users/nes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BearAcademy-cabkimmshebxeicjmqphvvwbpzmc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BearAcademy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BearAcademy.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Can you give some context as to what was going on when the error occurred? Errors are more easily diagnosed with context.

Comment: if I understand your comment correctly, the content of the question is updated

Comment: The answer is in the following comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719379/10353503

Comment: This just started happening to me suddenly in Xcode 11.4, even if I create a brand new project with a blank Asset Catalog! Please let me know if you find any solution. I've tried all of the answers to similar questions on here (even fully reinstalling Xcode) and none have solved it.

Comment: For what it's worth, installing the new Xcode 11.4.1 update fixed the issue for me (after installing it, I did another project build clean and deleted everything in `iOS DeviceSupport` & `DerivedData` from library/Developer/Xcode, just to be sure). Really hope this update fixes it for you too; is a very disheartening issue!