# 'Multiple commands produce' error not resolving

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting these errors when trying to archive my app for the App Store. During testing these never resent themselves. I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce) but the solution doesn't work for me as I don't have the offending files in that build phase. I am using pods to install, so I don't know if that would make the solution different.

```
1) Target 'Realm-iOS11.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Realm.framework'
2) Target 'Realm-iOS12.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Realm.framework'
```

Second error

```
1) Target 'RealmSwift-iOS11.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/RealmSwift.framework'
2) Target 'RealmSwift-iOS12.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/RealmSwift.framework'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was typing this out I poked around some more and eventually figured it out. I tried to deintegrate and reinstall pods, but it failed because there are different targets of the project that were using different versions of Swift. After I matched all targets to the same version of Swift and installed, everything was fine.

Comment: I am having the same issue with multiple Target files. Can you please tell me how did you match all targets to the same version of swift and installed them? Thank you!

Comment: @hasib_ullah In your project settings go to Build Settings and search for Swift version

Answer (score 0):

Clear your Derived Data folder.
You can go to `File` > `Workspace Settings` if you are in a workspace environment or `File` > `Project Settings` for a regular project environment.

Then click over the little grey arrow under `Derived data` section and select your project folder to delete it.

Comment: I had tried that as well, but archiving would bring me right back to the problem again. It's because the app I was working with is a target in a larger project, and not all of the targets were using the same version of Swif.t

Answer (score 0):

Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Example:

```
target 'theProject' do
  platform :ios, '12.0'
  use_frameworks!
# some pod
end

target 'theWidgetExtension' do
  platform :ios, '12.0'
  use_frameworks!
# some pod
end
```

You must using the same version of Pod library. Please read more in your terminal.