# Error in Xcode after deleting podfile.lock and running pod install

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've got a problem adding firebase to my podfile after updating to Catalina, and I deleted existing podfile.lock and run pod install, it run without any errors, but the problem now is inside Xcode

[image]

Comment: Have you ever tried clean project? CMD + SHIFT + K

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem I've tried this, but it didn't help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce Have you looked at these solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce)

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem Thank you a lot, it actually did help