# Where can I find Copy Bundle Ressources in xCode 12

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error during compilation

> Multiple commands produce ....

After googling, I think this might happen because I have several `info.plist` files.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce) answere I can find the several `info.plist` files here

`Solution -> Open target -> Build phases > Copy Bundle Resources`

However, the person who wrote this answere uses an older version of xCode.
I use xCode 12 and I am not sure where I can find `Copy Bundle Resources`
This is how my screen looks like

[image: Screenshot xCode 12]

Comment: You're in the `Build Settings` tab, `Build Phases` is next to it. It will be a list of phases that includes `Copy Bundle Resources`.

Comment: Did not follow directions. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As EmilioPelaez indicated at the comment, you need to check out the section written `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases`. Here is the SS.

[image]

Comment: Just to add for future people, if you don't see the `Copy Bundle Resources` section, you need to add it using the `+` button in the top left of the `Build Phases` screen.