# Multiple commands produce '<execute-shell-script-03d1f596c9a4df932ccd5e495eb58f9cc5126496f7a6912b6e5ac3373a118435>'

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode12

Gettig me error in my error like below. I have spand more time and try to find out the solution but not getting. One time run code successfully then run again getting again error.I have try many solutions but not working. Can you please help me if any one know about this error. Getting me different-different types errors,

Multiple commands produce<execute-shell-script 03d1f596c9a4df932ccd5e495eb58f9cc5126496f7a6912b6e5ac3373a118435>

1. That command depends on command in Target 'PorjectName' (project 'PorjectName'): script phase “Build Project Frameworks”
2. That command depends on command in Target 'notificationServiceExt' (project 'PorjectName'): script phase “Build Project Frameworks”

Multiple commands produce<execute-shell-script 03d1f596c9a4df932ccd5e495eb58f9c78de48a5f94cc0faf48e42df7a722246>

1. That command depends on command in Target 'PorjectName' (project 'PorjectName'): script phase “Build Assets Catalog”
2. That command depends on command in Target 'notificationServiceExt' (project 'PorjectName'): script phase “Build Assets Catalog”

Multiple commands produce<execute-shell-script 03d1f596c9a4df932ccd5e495eb58f9c6f40fa7bffc2d3568f75b6ec833c5>

1. That command depends on command in Target 'PorjectName' (project 'PorjectName'): script phase “Compile Binary Libraries”
2. That command depends on command in Target 'notificationServiceExt' (project 'PorjectName'): script phase “Compile Binary Libraries”

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce

Comment: Yes @AhmetSinaUstem i have tried and in my project Solution -> Open target -> Build phases > Copy Bundle Resources there is no any `info.plist`. Also tried In Xcode, go to File->Project/Workspace settings and Change the build system to Legacy Build system but not working.