# Xcode build issue after creating two different schemes of development and production

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build

I created two schemes with configurations one for development and one for production. And i just moved the info.plist file to another folder called configs.

Now when I try to build I get this build error.

> Multiple commands produce '/Users/keghamkarsian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Etadweer-fdhqhseczzvpnebpsxgxctnzasvc/Build/Products/Debug (Development)-iphoneos/Etadweer.app/Info.plist':

> 1. Target 'Etadweer' (project 'Etadweer') has copy command from '/Users/keghamkarsian/Documents/APPS/Etadweer/Etadweer/Configs/Info.plist' to '/Users/keghamkarsian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Etadweer-fdhqhseczzvpnebpsxgxctnzasvc/Build/Products/Debug (Development)-iphoneos/Etadweer.app/Info.plist'

> 2. Target 'Etadweer' (project 'Etadweer') has process command with output '/Users/keghamkarsian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Etadweer-fdhqhseczzvpnebpsxgxctnzasvc/Build/Products/Debug (Development)-iphoneos/Etadweer.app/Info.plist'

I tried reinstalling the pods, updating the Cocoapods, I tried deleting the info.plist file from the build phases copy bundle resources it displays another error that it could't locate the plist file. So I have to add it to the target again.

What should I do now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce)

Comment: I tried all answers in this question nothing helped. Plus I don't want to build it with legacy system.

Comment: Did you try to remove `Etadweer-fdhqhseczzvpnebpsxgxctnzasvc` folder from your `DerivedData` folder? At path `/Users/keghamkarsian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Etadweer-fdhqhseczzvpnebpsxgxctnzasvc`

Comment: By the way you can create multiple versions of .plist-files. For example, `DebugInfo.plist`, `ReleaseInfo.plist` and create the group (it has to create folder in your project) in XCode (context menu on your files-tree -> `New group`). This folder has to be yellow (group), not blue (folder-reference). And in `Build settings` of your target (not project) you can set path for every type of scheme (for example `configs/DebugInfo.plist` for `Debug`, `configs/ReleaseInfo.plist` for `Release`). Also look at your `Build phases`. May be you've added custom script which destroys your app build.

Comment: @ZhebzhikBabich Yes tried. Useless. Yes I checked the custom scripts but they are related to Crashlytics. And some stuff related to the pods.

Comment: @ZhebzhikBabich I solved it when I built the dev and prod schemes on release mode. The issue was only on debug mode.