# Xcode 13.2.1 . Multiple commands produce issue

Tags: ios, xcode

Showing Recent Messages

Prepare build
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/TME3/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TME3.app/Info.plist':

1. Target 'TME3' (project 'TME3') has copy command from '/Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/Info.plist' to '/Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/TME3/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TME3.app/Info.plist'
2. Target 'TME3' (project 'TME3') has process command with output '/Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/TME3/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TME3.app/Info.plist'

Analyze workspace
Create build description
Build description signature: a3e2dffff5e1e6f499ca380b47fc32ef
Build description path: /Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/TME3/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/a3e2dffff5e1e6f499ca380b47fc32ef-desc.xcbuild

Build target TME3 of project TME3 with configuration Debug
/Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/TME3.xcodeproj: warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file '/Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/Info.plist'. (in target 'TME3' from project 'TME3')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/TME3/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TME3.app/Info.plist' on task: ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/DerivedData/TME3/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TME3.app/Info.plist /Users/nickhunterblair/Projects/TME3/TME3/obj/Xcode/1/Info.plist (in target 'TME3' from project 'TME3')

Build failed    06/02/2022, 00:54    1.8 seconds

Comment: did any of these answer helped? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce

Comment: No I removed plist file from the copy bundle resources folder and another error showed up. when I quit the project and reloaded the file reappeared same thing when I made the project legacy build. this is a new issue with Xcode 13.2

Comment: This is the error when I rebuilt without plist.
Showing Recent Messages
Entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64

Answer (score 3):

Also that happens when you have 2 or more files with the same name