# Xcode 14: Still getting error 'Multiple commands produce ...'

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I am on Xcode 14.2, OSX 12.6.2. I have a project in cpp that used to build with no errors, then, all of a sudden, when I build it I get the error message

'Multiple commands produce '/Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nick_code-cjwqumczsrtixwabnmwivkxbmsrs/Build/Products/Debug/nick_code.app'

None of the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce) nor [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681831) work: in fact, the 'Copy bundle resources' dropdown menu is empty, see screenshot attached. [image]

Do you have any ideas to fix this ? Thanks!